# asp.net mvc 3 page can not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

This is the first time i have deployed asp.net mvc application on IIS 7.X.

If I deploy the application on the root path then it works fine but if I deploy on non-root path as mentioned below then only my home page works, none of the other links work.

http://rootpath/MyApplication/

Now lets say, I have controller - MyController and Action - MyAction. On execution of it, i am expecting http://rootpath/MyApplication/MyController/MyAction but it points to the rootpath only. (current output - http://rootpath/MyController/MyAction)

I haven't changed default routing. I have published the site with "File System" option.

```
/////// Code of Global.asax ///////
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            bool isBypassOn = false;

            if (!isBypassOn)
            {
                //Following should be default application route path
                routes.MapRoute(
                    "Default", // Route name
                    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                    new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
                );
            }
            else
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                   "Default", // Route name
                   "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                   new { controller = "ByPassLogin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
               );

            }
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
```

//Some controller code

public class MemberHomeController : BaseController
    {
        //
        // GET: /MemberHome/

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //return Content("Successful Login...");
        return View();
    }

    public override void Custom_OnLoad()
    {
        SelectedMenu = Menus.Home;
    }

    public ActionResult ScheduleIndex()
    {
        //return Content("Successful Login...");
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: post your controller and global.asax

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
routes.MapRoute( "Default",
             "MyApplication/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } );
```

instead of the default.